# Pandas - different aggregations for a field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a transaction table with these columns: customer_id, transaction_id, month

I would like to write a query which will be equivalent to the following in SQL:

```
SELECT min(month) as first_month, max(month) as last_month
FROM transactions
GROUP BY customer_id
```

in pandas, it seems I can only aggregate every column once, e.g the following query will return only one month column:

```
transactions.groupby('customer_id').aggregate({ 'Month' : 'min', 'Month' : 'max'})
```

Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
transactions.groupby('customer_id').aggregate({ 'Month' : ['min', 'max']})
```

Sample:

```
transactions = pd.DataFrame({'customer_id':[1,2,3,1,2,1],
                   'Month':      [4,5,6,1,1,3]})

print (transactions)
   Month  customer_id
0      4            1
1      5            2
2      6            3
3      1            1
4      1            2
5      3            1

df = transactions.groupby('customer_id').aggregate({ 'Month' : ['min', 'max']})
print (df)
            Month    
              min max
customer_id          
1               1   4
2               1   5
3               6   6
```

Faster solution is:

```
g = transactions.groupby('customer_id')['Month']
print (pd.concat([g.min(), g.max()], axis=1, keys=['min','max']))
```